# Binding vs Polymorphism

Tags: oop, polymorphism, late-binding, early-binding

Is there any direct relationship between Late Binding and Overriding, similarly for Early Binding and Overloading?

They (Binding/Overriding/Overloading) can be termed as ways to implement polymorphism, but is there any "Direct Relationship" ex: Late Binding is a sub/super concept to Overriding and vice versa etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are orthogonal (independent) concepts.

- Overloading, Overriding: Forms of polymorphism
- Early binding/Late binding: In the former, the method to call is known at compile time. In the latter, at runtime.

Of course, an implementation of overriding **usually** implies using late binding, because you will only know the object's real type at runtime. But that's just a special case.

Comment: So can it be termed Overriding is based on Late Binding and overloading on Early binding - "ALWAYS"?

Comment: That's the typical scenario, but it can be different. Suppose you have a base class `Pet`, and derived classes `Dog` and `Cat`, and a virtual method `Speak` overriden in both derived classes. If a compiler/interpreter sees the following statements: `Pet p = new Dog(); p.Speak();`, it has enough information to perform early binding (it knows that p will always be a `Dog`).

Comment: Good!! Got the meaning of usually now :) Thanks.